# Borrar un objeto en Groovy

Tags: java, groovy, bonita

Estoy usando bonitaSoft , y quiero borrar un objeto en una tarea humana , mi objeto es **curso** , y lo que hago simplemente en el script es `curso = null;`

Pero me salta este error:

> "curso" dependency cannot be inicialized or update inside a groovy
>   script expresion. You have to use an Operation.

¿A qué se puede deber?

He probado esto , pero sigue sin servir , se sigue creando el objeto.

```
if(!(aux=="aprobado")) {
    def c = cursoDAO.newInstance();
    c=null;
}
```

Comment: podrías poner más detalle para poder ayudarte.

Answer (score 0):

Para borrar una instancia de un objeto en Bonita, debes ir a la opción Operaciones, y crear una operación donde selecciones la instancia que deseas eliminar y el operador Is deleted.

Te sugiero que cuando vayas a eliminar una instancia crees una tarea de servicio y dentro de ella, insertes la operación que te indique anteriormente.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Mira Cómo responder para que tu respuesta sea mejor recibida. También, aprovecha y haz el recorrido para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera medalla!